# Cakephp ajax update validation w3c

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, w3c, cakephp-ajaxhelper

can somebody help me validate this error ?

[Validator w3C](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://test2.oknihach.eu/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3)
on my [site](http://test2.oknihach.eu)

Or have idea how I can show content in Jdialog? 
Sorry for my english ...

Comment: Can you please post the CakePHP code used to generate this code?

Comment: It should be simple ajax link 
`echo $ajax->link('Prihlásenie',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'), array('id'=>'prihlas','update'=>'okno'));`

Answer (score 0):

This is because an old version of Cake considered those extra options as properties on the link. This was fixed a while ago, so consider upgrading your version of Cake to remove it and allow validation to pass.

Comment: And Is there any solution without upgrading cake? I almost finished this project and the upgrade would be a bit complicated

Comment: Yes, but it involves modifying the core code, which is never a good idea. You'll have to replace the `/cake/libs/view/helpers/ajax.php` file with a new one, or modify the `link()` method to remove it from the html options. I couldn't even find the version you're using, so I can't specifically tell you what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I provisionally edited the link() method in  Ajax helper until I finish the upgrade version of the cake... Thanks a lot